# Cant access cell from willDisplayCell method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two methods which are changing accerssory type of a cell.
First is called after all cells are loaded, the other one is called when user clicks on any cell.

Second method works fine, it removes checkmark from selected cell. Unfortunately the first one does nothing (I want to add checkmark to one of the cells). It makes me confused, beceause theese methods should work the same, shouldnt they?

```
// First method
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]
lastObject]).row) 
    {
        LanguageTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:myNumber inSection:0]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}

// Second method
- (void)tableView:(UITableView )tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    LanguageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:myNumber inSection:0]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

I tried to change class of cell, but its still not working. Im not sure if first function is called in right time = after viewDidLoad...
Thanks for help!

Comment: Quite creative approach ) What is "myNumber"? Is it a constant?

Comment: A side note: if you are re-using your cells you are going to get some issues with how you are doing things here. If you show an accessoryCheckmark on the cell without any data source reference then when you scroll down or up that cell may be re-used and you will see a checkmark where you do not expect it. I assume you only have a few roles appearing in your table currently, hence why you have not noticed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `- (__kindofUITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Comment: I see, I have defined cell twice. Thanks!